# mkdirs failed to create folder with unicode character?

Tags: android, unicode, mkdir

I'm trying to make a folder in sdcard programatically. So I used the following code:

```
String file_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/محاضرات;
File dir = new File(file_path);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

This code works well when i used "lectures" instead of "محاضرات" . So the problem is the Unicode characters. Any help will be appericated. How can i create a folder with unicode letters not ascii code?

Comment: Does logcat say something?

Comment: no.. and with debug the complier executed mkdirs ! the problem is on DDMS , file explorer the folder not exist. and when i try to add a file to this folder logcat says "no such file or directory" !